# Why am I getting permission denied? Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write csv files to a sub-directory based on the name of the files in a different sub-directory. (from TimeSeries to Country Stats)

```
source1 = "C:/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/Corona Stats/TimeSeries"
path1 = "C:/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/Corona Stats/Country Series/"


def country_csv():
    # loop through absolute paths of each file in source
    for filename in os.listdir(source1):
        filepath = os.path.join(source1, filename)
        if not os.path.isfile(filepath):
            continue
        df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
        df = df.groupby(['Country']).sum()
        df = df.reset_index()
        df.to_csv(os.path.join(filepath, path1))


country_csv()
```

Gives me"

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/Corona Stats/Country Series/'
```

I had written them to TimeSeries by accident by doing:

```
df.to_csv(os.path.join(path1, filepath))
```

Doing just:

```
df.to_csv(path1)
```

Yields the same permission denied error.

Comment: `print( os.path.join(filepath, path1) )` and you will see you forgot to add filename. You can't write to folder. You have to add ie `output.csv` at the end

Comment: OR maybe instead of `filepath` you should add only `filename` to `path1` - `os.path.join(path1, filename)` . You can't join two absolute pathes. -  `C:/path1` + `C:/path2` ?

Comment: BTW: next time use `print()` to see what path you try to use - `print(os.path.join(path1, filepath))` and `print(path1)` and `print(filepath)`

Comment: this part 
```os.path.join(filepath, path1)``` is wrong in your ```df.to_csv``` line, you are merging two directories which will output another directory, you cannot write to a directory. it could be for example ```os.path.join(path1, filename)```